# RowAction in LWC datatable to redirect to external site

Tags: lightning-web-components, datatable, browser

I am using rowaction with type as 'action' in lwc datatable. Clicking on which should redirect to external site. First I tried using window.open in the handlerowaction method as below

```
handleRowAction(event){
    const actionName = event.detail.action.name;
    const row = event.detail.row;
    this.record = row;
    console.log('new value '+this.record.new_value);
    window.open(this.record.new_value);
}
```

this.record.new_value logs correctly such as - www.google.com in the console log. However, in the UI when I click on rowaction , it redirects to as - InstanceURL/lightning/r/case/{caseId}/view/www.google.com which is nothing but the current page url (Salesforce UI) + external site url . Not sure what I am missing here.

Secondly, I tried using `import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';` and the handlerowaction method as below

```
handleRowAction(event){
    const actionName = event.detail.action.name;
    const row = event.detail.row;
    this.record = row;
    console.log('new value '+this.record.new_value);
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'standard__webPage',
    attributes: {
        url: this.record.new_value
    }
},
true // Replaces the current page in your browser history with the URL
```

);
    }

In this case it throws error at the UI level with message pop up as - This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. First, would you give us some details? (We're reporting this as error ID: -2015273290)

Any idea what could be wrong? An alternative way to redirect external to Salesforce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using just `www.google.com`, you're asking for a *relative file path*. Instead, specify either `//www.google.com/` (the server www.google.com using the current protocol, typically https) or `https://www.google.com/` (the server www.google.com using the https protocol). The latter is the preferred form.

## Relative

```
some-file.name
```

## Absolute (Same Server)

```
/path/some-file.name
```

## Absolute (Any Server, Same Protocol)

```
//server/path/some-file.name
```

## Canonical (Any Server, Any Protocol

```
https://server/path/some-file.name
```